# show and hide <ul>

Tags: jquery, css

```
 let opened = false;
 function turnNestedlist(opened)
 {
     elem = countImg;
   $(`.list__ul .nested-list.num-${elem}`).click(function(event)
    {
      if (!opened){
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(`.list__ul .nested-list.num-${elem}.active li`).show("fast");
        opened = true;
      }
      $(this).click(function(event)
      {
        if (opened){
         $(this).removeClass('active');
         $(`.list__ul .nested-list.num-${elem} li`).hide("fast");
         opened = false;
        }
      });
    });
  }
  $(`.list__ul .nested-list.num-${countImg}`).click(turnNestedlist(opened));
```

The task is that when you click on each list `ul`, 4 nested elements of the `li` element open. This code works, but for each `ul` element only once, that is: the first click occurred - the list was closed, the second click-opened, the third click-the list opens and closes immediately.

[image: 1]

Comment: as long as you do not show what you have tampered with with your HTML, it is impossible to answer you  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  ++ https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example -- A picture doesn't help SHOW YOUR HTML CSS of that !

Comment: `.click(turnNestedlist(opened))` is already wrong. With that, you would be _calling_ the function in that place, and assign its return value as the click handler function. But your function does not return a function object, so this makes no sense to begin with.

Comment: Note that adding event handlers in event handlers is a distinct code smell.